# Why isn't the jquery :not() selector working as I expect it to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to set an event that fires when anything WITHOUT the `.four` class is clicked. However, it fires when things with the `.four` class are clicked, even though I'm using `e.stopPropagation()`.

```
$("html").one("click", ":not(.four)", function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log("Something without class 'four' was clicked that had class: " + $(e.srcElement).attr("class") );
});
```

​([jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/KUL9U/))

This does not work either:

```
$("html").not('.four').on("click", function(e){
```

Both output: `Something without class 'four' was clicked that had class: four`

I'm having tons of trouble with `:not()` and I suspect a lot of it might have to do with my browser supporting CSS3 `:not()` now, but I still can't understand this simple issue.

Comment: +1 Good question. I'm on it.

Comment: So you just want to ensure that when `.four` is clicked that the event doesn't fire, right? I'm just trying to be clear.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes, every element on the page **except** `.four` should have a click event delegated by `html`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code:

```
$("html").one("click", ":not(.four)", function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // other code
});
```

sets up global event delegation for the click event type. This means that whenever a click event is triggered at **any** element on the page, jQuery will check if that element matches the provided selector - `":not(.four)"` - and if it does, jQuery will invoke the handler on that element.

This is what happens when you click on a `.four` element:

1. The original element at which the click event is triggered is obviously the `.four` element. jQuery checks if that element matches the `":not(.four)"` selector. Since it doesn't, the handler is **not** invoked on that element.
2. Click events bubble up the DOM tree. As propagation for this click event has not been canceled yet, the event triggers at the next element, which is the parent of the original element - the `.two` element in your demo. Again, jQuery checks if the element matches the selector. Since it does, the handler is invoked on that element.

As you can see, your handler *will* be invoked even if you click on a `.four` element. In order to prevent the code from being executed when a `.four` element is clicked, you have to explicitly check within the handler - basically what Jason's solution does.

Comment: in reality there is no propagation since click is delegated to `html` and selector is the `target`. Event is already ocuring at top of treee. So stopPropogation isn't effective in delegation

Comment: yes but could be great to find out a solution :/ if anyone has, also cause this is a big jquery bug as i can see from the jquery doc

Comment: @charlietfl No, it' not. `e.stopPropagation()` cancels the propagation successfully. OP's handler is only invoked once.

Comment: @Badaboooooom What do you mean? This works as expected. I don't see a bug.

Comment: what works? your code? i'm blind ? cause i can't see any improvements or fixs... :/

Comment: @Badaboooooom OP's code behaves as expected. There is no bug here.

Comment: i mean what's the pourpouse of your question? can't undertsand sorry

Comment: @Badaboooooom My question? I provided an answer, not a question.

Comment: @Badaboooooom My answer explains why OP's code behaves the way it behaves.

Comment: OP posted a code that wasn't performing as expected.  Šime explains why it is working as intended.  I provided a workaround.

Comment: oh understood, thanks, so no fixies at all yet .uhm really courious

Answer (score 2):

As Šime Vidas pointed out, this is the desired workaround:

```
function doThisOnce(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();

   if(!$(this).is(".four")){
        console.log("Something without class 'four' was clicked that had class: " + $(e.srcElement).attr("class"));
        $(".one").addClass("pretty");
    }
    else {
        // need to rebind the click event
        $(document).one("click", "*", doThisOnce);
    }
}
$(document).one("click", "*", doThisOnce);
```

Comment: That's a good workaround, though I'd have to re-register the listener again (since it's `.one()` not `.on()`) but ultimately I'd rather figure out what the deal is with `:not()` instead of giving up on it without even knowing what I was doing wrong.

Comment: I agree.  Not finding any love in their bug tracking software.  Kind of a weird issue to search for.

Comment: @Badaboooooom Which is exactly why I said it's a bug in my answer.  It is a legitimate workaround.

Comment: sure, but could be great to fix issues not to workaround , workarounds are for newbies :D joking

Comment: That's the way to do it. Btw, I like do bind global event delegation on the `document` object, e.g. `$(document).on('click', '*', ...`, since the `document` reference is built-in. (`$('html')` performs a DOM query.)

Comment: @JasonWhitted, again, thanks for this workaround, but in the end, once I realized what the problem was (thanks @Šime Vidas), I was able to solve my actual issue without needing the `:not()` or a workaround for it at all! (Basically, I'm just preventing event bubbling with other listeners, much like the answer I just added to this question.)

Comment: **It's not a bug**. It's how DOM events work. When you use jQuery `live()`--though now the syntax in jQuery is `.on( , 'selector')`-- you get a [bubbling phase](http://catcode.com/domcontent/events/capture.html). Since the class `.four `element is entirely contained within a parent, if you click on it, the *parent* element's click event also fires. `srcElement` detects the actual clicked item `.four`, but if you examine the jQuery `event.target` and `event.relatedTarget` you will see what is going on: you also need to exclude clicks eventing in the parent that originated in the child.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution I want to contribute. Put this listener alongside the other one:

```
$("html").one("click", ".four", function(e){
       e.stopPropagation();
});
$("html").one("click", function(e){
    // other code
});
```

It will prevent propagation on `.four` and "steal" or "catch" it from bubbling up to the other listener. It might be helpful to have the "catcher" listener at a lower level than the other one, depending on if it bubbles up to one before the other.

See the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/KUL9U/66/), working, finally!

Comment: Not quite working for me.  If you click `.four` twice it selects it.  Because each one of the click events is getting registered as a `.one()`

Comment: Because it is de-regestering itself. For the purpose of this demo, you can turn the "catcher" to `.on()` and it will work no matter how many times you click.

Comment: You can shorten your code a little like this: `$("html").one("click", ".four", false);` By passing `false` instead of a function, jQuery will assign a handler that invokes `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using the event `target`:

```
$(document).one("click", function(e){
    if( ! $(e.target).closest('.four').length ){
         console.log("Something without class 'four' was clicked that had class: " + $(e.srcElement).attr("class") );
     }
});
```

`closest()` will match children of the class as well as the class element itself